# Jersey error running as server (Tomcat)

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, jersey

My problem is when I rus as server any applications that use Jersey. 
In the last test I used this tutorial:
http://www.java2blog.com/2016/03/restful-web-services-jaxrs-crud-example.html
The problem (is the same for every project) is:

```html
GRAVE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
nov 26, 2016 11:09:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

nov 26, 2016 11:09:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [Jersey REST Service] in web application [/JAXRS-Example] threw load() exception
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

nov 26, 2016 11:09:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: Marking servlet Jersey Web Application as unavailable
nov 26, 2016 11:09:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [Jersey Web Application] in web application [/JerseyHibernateApp2] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

nov 26, 2016 11:09:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: Marking servlet jersey-serlvet as unavailable
nov 26, 2016 11:09:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [jersey-serlvet] in web application [/ProvaJersey] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

nov 26, 2016 11:09:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAZIONI: Marking servlet helloworld as unavailable
nov 26, 2016 11:09:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [helloworld] in web application [/helloworld] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

nov 26, 2016 11:09:16 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
nov 26, 2016 11:09:17 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
nov 26, 2016 11:09:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
GRAVE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MavenJersey]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MavenJersey]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
 ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@5fb0ac60]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4927)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5057)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
 ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@485f0b6f]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
 at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:699)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
 ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
 at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:139)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
 ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet.initInternal(JarResourceSet.java:137)
 ... 13 more

nov 26, 2016 11:09:19 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
nov 26, 2016 11:09:20 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFORMAZIONI: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey
nov 26, 2016 11:09:20 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFORMAZIONI: Root resource classes found:
  class com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.HelloWorldREST
  class com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.controller.CountryController
nov 26, 2016 11:09:20 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFORMAZIONI: No provider classes found.
nov 26, 2016 11:09:20 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFORMAZIONI: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
nov 26, 2016 11:09:21 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
nov 26, 2016 11:09:21 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAZIONI: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
nov 26, 2016 11:09:21 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFORMAZIONI: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.jd
nov 26, 2016 11:09:21 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFORMAZIONI: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.14 09/09/2012 05:39 PM'
nov 26, 2016 11:09:22 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
GRAVE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
nov 26, 2016 11:09:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
GRAVE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1300)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:163)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:760)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
 at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
 at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

nov 26, 2016 11:09:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
GRAVE: Servlet [Jersey REST Service] in web application [/my-jersey-project] threw load() exception
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1300)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:163)
 at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
.
.
.
```

In particular, the error: GRAVE: "Servlet [......] in web application [/......] threw load() exception" it is common in other applications. I try to resolve searching on internet (also on stackoverflow) but doesn't work. In fact, doesn't work neither the project downloading from the site above. 
This is my pom.xml:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.arpit.java2blog</groupId>
 <artifactId>JAXRSJsonCRUDExample</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>JAXRSJsonCRUDExample Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <properties>
        <jersey.version>1.18.3</jersey.version>
    </properties>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 <build>
  <finalName>JAXRSJsonCRUDExample</finalName>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.7</source>
     <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>


   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

and this is web.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
   <param-value>org.arpit.java2blog.controller</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

CountryController.java

```html
package org.arpit.java2blog.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.arpit.java2blog.bean.Country;
import org.arpit.java2blog.service.CountryService;


@Path("/countries")
public class CountryController {
 
 CountryService countryService=new CountryService();
 
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public List<Country> getCountries()
 {
  
  List<Country> listOfCountries=countryService.getAllCountries();
  return listOfCountries;
 }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Country getCountryById(@PathParam("id") int id)
 {
  return countryService.getCountry(id);
 }
   
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Country addCountry(Country country)
 {
  return countryService.addCountry(country);
 }

    @PUT
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Country updateCountry(Country country)
 {
  return countryService.updateCountry(country);
  
 }
 
    @DELETE
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public void deleteCountry(@PathParam("id") int id)
 {
   countryService.deleteCountry(id);
  
 }
 
}
```

CountryService.java

```html
package org.arpit.java2blog.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.arpit.java2blog.bean.Country;

/*
 * It is just a helper class which should be replaced by database implementation.
 * It is not very well written class, it is just used for demonstration.
 */
public class CountryService {

 static HashMap<Integer,Country> countryIdMap=getCountryIdMap();


 public CountryService() {
  super();

  if(countryIdMap==null)
  {
   countryIdMap=new HashMap<Integer,Country>();
  // Creating some object of countries while initializing
   Country indiaCountry=new Country(1, "India",10000);
   Country chinaCountry=new Country(4, "China",20000);
   Country nepalCountry=new Country(3, "Nepal",8000);
   Country bhutanCountry=new Country(2, "Bhutan",7000);


   countryIdMap.put(1,indiaCountry);
   countryIdMap.put(4,chinaCountry);
   countryIdMap.put(3,nepalCountry);
   countryIdMap.put(2,bhutanCountry);
  }
 }

 public List<Country> getAllCountries()
 {
  List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>(countryIdMap.values());
  return countries;
 }

 public Country getCountry(int id)
 {
  Country country= countryIdMap.get(id);
  return country;
 }
 public Country addCountry(Country country)
 {
  country.setId(countryIdMap.size()+1);
  countryIdMap.put(country.getId(), country);
  return country;
 }
 
 public Country updateCountry(Country country)
 {
  if(country.getId()<=0)
   return null;
  countryIdMap.put(country.getId(), country);
  return country;

 }
 public void deleteCountry(int id)
 {
  countryIdMap.remove(id);
 }

 public static HashMap<Integer, Country> getCountryIdMap() {
  return countryIdMap;
 }


}
```

Comment: Try path as just countries instead of /countries

Comment: I already tried it, but nothing...doesn't works

Comment: You are using a.old Jersey version i guess right?

Comment: The strange thing is that give me similar errors for any Jersey Project

Comment: To use jersey I just have to enter the correct libraries? however to have tried other jersery projects, I also tried the project created by my professor that already includes all the libraries jersey, so I do not think it's the version the problem, given that those are the libraries and the professor works

Comment: I feel there is some problem with your pom.xml , i will check and get back .If you are desperate to check you can try  any archetype by maven for jersey

Comment: No, I don't think that it is a pom.xml problem. My professor doesn't use Maven, his project doesn't have pom.xml, but give me the same error of the project above

Comment: The same thing using this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/ ..same error... It can be Tomcat?

Comment: Have you tried starting Tomcat without your application.can you view tomcat local host.page

Comment: Tomcat works without my application: in http://localhost:8080/ I can see Tomcat's homepage

Comment: Can you post it somewhere i can recreate like a online repository

Comment: This is the first time that I use a repository. I used BitBucket, this is the url of my repo (not private). https://Aragorn1992@bitbucket.org/Aragorn1992/jaxrsjsoncrudexample.git
Tell me if all right

Comment: your code is working fine there is no issue , there is something wrong with the tomcat server i guess , Please create a new Server and then try this is the best i can tell

Comment: Now it works! Thank you! I create a new server and configure another root for Tomcat. Thanks a lot, if you answer I make your answer as favorite

Comment: However, it show only the text "Hello Worlds", is it true? But in CountryControl.java there are this annotation: "@Path("/countries")"
If i change the url in "http://localhost:8080/JAXRSJsonCRUDExample/countries", should it works? Because appear to me: "HTTP Status 404 - /JAXRSJsonCRUDExample/countries"

Comment: you have to use /rest/countries , appent it to the url you see getting opened automatically in the browser

Comment: use this localhost:8080/JAXRSJsonCRUDExample/rest/countries, the webservice is open at rest/ it is mapped in web.xml

Comment: Well, but now it give me this error: "HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error"

Comment: You will have to check that or post another question , i would suggest you to please read some tutorials to begin with

Comment: Ok thanks. Now I will search for resolve this error and also I will search for a tutorial, if I can not solve, I will post another question. Thanks

Comment: Only a question: "localhost:8080/JAXRSJsonCRUDExample/rest/countries" work on your pc?

Comment: Yes it worked that is the reason i told i works .
And for tutorials You can follow this https://javabrains.io/courses/javaee_jaxrs,This is for begineers